# Python Existing connection forcibly closed by remote host Pandas read SQL and to sql functions different databases

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to read sql from one database and put the data into a dataframe. And then I want that dataframe to be written to a sql table in another database. Each time I try to do this I get the following error:

```
TCP Provider: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.\r\n (10054) (SQLExecute); [08S01] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Communication link failure (10054)')
```

The code works when I read sql from one database and put the dataframe into a sql table in the SAME database.

My 2 connections are enginemb and engine. I am reading from enginemb and then I want to use the df to write into a sql table into engine

Example code of engine connection string. I have the same for enginemb but with different server and user credentials:

```
     # SQL CONNECTION TO DAMDB
    params = urllib.parse.quote_plus("DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};"
                                     "SERVER=server.database.windows.net;"
                                     "DATABASE=db;"
                                     "UID=admin;"
                                     "PWD=**********")

engine = db.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}".format(params))





 def write_to_df():
        # Added to make insert into SQL faster using cursor.fast_executemany
        @event.listens_for(enginemb, 'before_cursor_execute')
        def plugin_bef_cursor_execute(conn, cursor, statement, params, context, executemany):
            if executemany:
                cursor.fast_executemany = True

        df = pd.read_sql(sql='EXEC [prod].[spData]?', con=enginemb,
                                           params=['A'])
        return df


def write_db(df):
        # Added to make insert into SQL faster using cursor.fast_executemany
        @event.listens_for(engine, 'before_cursor_execute')
        def plugin_bef_cursor_execute(conn, cursor, statement, params, context, executemany):
            if executemany:
                cursor.fast_executemany = True

        df.to_sql('tblData', con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False,
                                    schema='tmp')

    def main():
        df= write_to_df()
        write_db(df)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```